# Youtube player api with loop

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am struggling with setting up the loop for youtube videos using youtube player api.

The problem is that the video is not running under a loop.

Here is my code

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',

          playerVars: {
            'controls': 0,           
            'showinfo': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'loop': 1

          },
          videoId: 'qzZuBWMnS08',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
           // 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
function onPlayerReady(event) {
        //  event.target.setLoop(true);
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
```

The loop:1 doesn't seem to be working.Also is there any way to remove the share and video title from the top of the video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55):

If the video isn't changing, you can just do

```js
onStateChange: 
    function(e) {
        if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.playVideo(); 
        }
    }
```

This will prevent unnecisarily reloading the video

Comment: +1 for the approach above because it will immediately play the video avoiding the quick flash of black screen that happens when one uses the "&playlist=VIDEO_ID" suggested  by [Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Comment: Great solution. Just FYI you can also play the video like this `e.target.playVideo()` to make it a bit more dynamic.

Comment: If for some reason (i.e using external module ) you can't get access to the variable YT and its properties  YT.PlayerState.ENDED is (at the time of writing this)  0, so you can substitute this for 0 .

Answer (score 19):

This is what I have used for the API IFrame video loop. I noticed that you must include "playlist:VIDEO_ID" parameter. and it works. This is my example

```html
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
      playerVars: {
        playlist: 'VIDEO_ID',
        loop: 1
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Experimenting with this on Android, I found that this only works if you call the javascript loadPlaylist() method, instead of loadVideo(). As a side-effect, this causes the YouTube web UI to show the playlist control, which allows the user to see a pop-up list of videos in the playlist. In the case where looping is wanted on a single video, this is an unwanted side-effect, as the UX feels clunky with a single-video playlist.

Answer (score 12):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), you need to set the [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist) parameter to the video ID in order for loop to work.

You'll be wanting the [showinfo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo) parameter to hide the title etc.

Comment: The problem of this method is that it loads the same video again as a new video.

Comment: Missed this. I can't check now, but wouldn't that be a non-issue as the browser should have the video cached/loaded from the previous playback?

Answer (score 8):

Try this in your *onPlayerStateChange*, in some sort of way Youtube wants you to put in the videoID again.

```
onStateChange: function(e){
    var id = 'qzZuBWMnS08';

    if(e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
        player.loadVideoById(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work to give me loop video with super low volume set for playing video. You can mute by changing volume from 2 to 0.

Also make sure your video is added to a playlist. Apparently that is an issue now. And use video id in both playlist and videoid areas in the code.

Im sure i have extra steps or redundant steps as im no coder.

I just know this works.

```
    <div id="player">
<script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '315',
          width: '600',
          videoId: 'DrrH-YTvVVc',
          playerVars: {
          playlist: 'DrrH-YTvVVc',
          loop: 1      }       ,
   events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
           event.target.setVolume(2);
       event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = true;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    //      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                  player.playVideo();
        }
           event.target.setVolume(2);
      }
</script></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Working loop example (02-2019)

```
<div id="ytplayer">
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      width: '640',
      height: '360',

          // 1. Video_Id
          videoId: 'AfAwsdbj04I',

      playerVars: { 
          autoplay: 1,
          loop: 1,
          controls: 0,
          rel: 0,
          modestbranding: 1,

          // 2. Playlist_Id (don't forget "PL")
          playlist: 'PLxWQS97ZR2-_c2eqKxSHxEu7v462-qnYM'

      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setVolume(80);
    event.target.playVideo();
 //  player.mute();
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(0);
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for sharing an answer. In general, people are looking for explanations, not code. Maybe try expanding your answer with some idea of why your suggestion works and/or what they were doing wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Since the html5 player, we can just right click on the video => play in loop.

From script, to replay at the end of the video:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream html5-main-video')[0].loop = true
```

**Loop 1.66 seconds between two time points:**

```
const video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream html5-main-video')[0]

/* Loop markers in seconds */
let start = 54.34, end = 56

/* Seek to time in seconds */
function seek(time){
  video.loop = true
  video.currentTime = time
  video.play()
}

/* Loop between start and end */
function loop(e){
  if (e.target.currentTime > end){
    seek(start)
  }
}

/* Will loop for 1.66s */
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", loop, false)

/* Seek to 54.34s */
seek(start)

/* Abort the loop */
// video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", loop, false)

/* New loop */
// start = 14; end = 15; seek(start)
```

[Media events list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Media_events)

[HTMLMediaElement reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)