# Why YouTube Player API loop doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, elementor

I don't know why.

I tried use Elementor Embed and now Im trying use YouTube Player API.

```
self.elements.$player = new YT.Player( this.elements.$swiperContainer.find( '.elementor-repeater-item-' + sliderID + ' .elementor-background-video-embed' )[ i ], {
            videoId: videoID,
            events: {
                'onReady': self.onPlayerReady,
            },
            playerVars: {
                controls: 0,
                rel: 0,
                autoplay: 1,
                loop: 1,
                start: videoStart,
                end: videoEnd,
            },
        } );
```

All options work, but not loop.
Iframe result:

```
<iframe class="elementor-background-video-embed" data-video-link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_dWvTCdDQ4" style="width: 762px; height: 428.625px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_dWvTCdDQ4?controls=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;start=50&amp;end=60&amp;widget_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fcmsmasters-elementor.net%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D738%26action%3Delementor&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fcmsmasters-elementor.net&amp;widgetid=17" id="widget18"></iframe>
```

Its gonna be Slider with video on background for Elementor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop option doesn't work in the youtube js api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795034/loop-option-doesnt-work-in-the-youtube-js-api)

Answer (score 0):

The question is already asked here [Loop option doesn't work in the youtube js api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795034/loop-option-doesnt-work-in-the-youtube-js-api)

According to the Youtube API doc, you should :

> "set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter
> value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL"

see Youtube API documentation here= https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop