# loop embeded youtube video without reload

Tags: html, youtube-api

i am making a webpage with a video that plays all the time.
i want this video to replay without loading the video from the internet everytime.
i tried the following code:

```
    <iframe id="frametube" allowfullscreen="1" width="100%" height="700px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx?version=3&loop=1&playlist=xxx&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"
        style="position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

but everytime the video ends, it reload again!
how can i prevent this?
if you check www.kolor.com the video continue playing and looping even if you turned off the internet after the first replay

Comment: Try the code implementation from this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410789/youtube-player-api-with-loop) where you execute player.playVideo() when the video state becomes ENDED. Since you're going to play the same video throughout, this might work for you.
Try looking into [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers) as it has the offline first feature where it can store/cache data and use them when the internet is disconnected.

Comment: Thank you @noogui,
this was what i want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube player api with loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410789/youtube-player-api-with-loop)

Comment: This question has already been answered. <br> Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play